# my vue app failed to compile because that error

Tags: vue.js

i just want to install vue via cli 
and this error shows up

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js)
[image]

Comment: Did you install eslint-loader module? You might also want to check the webpack config. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader

Comment: try : yarn add real-world-vue